# How to conditionally insert a record in table B during insert into table A in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Given the following structure:

Table A (`aliases`):

```
user_id | alias 
---------------
   1      john
   2      peter
```

`user_id` references `id` in `users`.

Table B (`users`):

```
  id | password_hash | ...
---------------------------
   1        ...        ...
   2        ...        ...
```

(the idea is that users can have multiple aliases all of which point to the same main user account record)

I would like to do the following operation: given an `alias, password, ...` record:

- if `alias` exists in `aliases`, update the corresponding `password` in `users`
- if `alias` does not exist, create a new user in `users` with the given password and insert a row into `aliases` pointing to this new record.

How can I do that in a single query in Postgres?

Something along the lines of

```
WITH (
  INSERT INTO users(id, password, ...) VALUES(DEFAULT, password, ...) RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO aliases(user_id, alias) VALUES(id, alias)
  ON CONFLICT {delete the temp row in users and update the one with the 
               known user_id instead}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that `users_id_seq` is the sequence used for `users.id` and that there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `aliases.alias`:

```
WITH a AS (INSERT INTO aliases (user_id, alias)
              VALUES (nextval('users_id_seq'), p_alias)
           ON CONFLICT (alias)
              /* this does nothing, but is needed for RETURNING */
              DO UPDATE
                 SET user_id = aliases.user_id
           RETURNING user_id
          )
INSERT INTO users (id, password_hash, ...)
   SELECT user_id, p_password, ...
      FROM a
ON CONFLICT (id)
   DO UPDATE
      SET password_hash = EXCLUDED.password_hash;
```

Comment: So, you are saying that immediate constraints are not checked at CTE boundaries? It would be convenient in this case.

Comment: I don't understand - which constraint?

Comment: on yes. I assumed one foreign key on the `aliases.user_id` (which should point to `users.id`). That one, at least in my example.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING user_id in the CTE part?

Comment: Yes, because then there would be no `RETURNING` data. It is not beautiful, but shouln't be a problem.

Comment: @pozs Oh, I see what you mean. The constraint is checked at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 2):

*Note*: I'll assume that `alias` is the primary key (but at least, it's a unique key) of `aliases`.

Unfortunately, because the unique column (`alias`) is not on the target table (of the `UPSERT`), you cannot do this with a single `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...` statement.

First, you'll need to define the foreign key on `aliases.user_id` (which refers to the `users.id` column) to be `DEFERRABLE` (it can be `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` though).

After that, these statements should be able to run (despite any concurrent modifications to these tables):

```
set constraints fk_aliases_user_id deferred;

with params(alias, pwd) as (
  values ('john', 'pass3'),
         ('jane', 'pass4')
),
inserted_alias as (
  insert into aliases(alias, user_id)
  select      alias, coalesce((select user_id
                               from   aliases a
                               where  a.alias = p.alias),
                              nextval('users_id_seq'))
  from        params p
  on conflict (alias) do nothing
  returning   *
)
insert into users(id, password_hash)
select      coalesce(i.user_id, a.user_id),
            crypt(p.pwd, gen_salt('bf'))
from        params p
left join   inserted_alias i using (alias)
left join   aliases a using (alias)
on conflict (id) do update
set         password_hash = excluded.password_hash;

set constraints fk_aliases_user_id immediate;
```

*Notes*:

- I used the `crypt()` function form the [`pgcrypto`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) module to generate `password_hash` from plain passwords. I hope you're doing something similar.
- This may cause gaps in the `users_id_seq` when the concurrency is high, but should always succeed (and I minimized the chances for that with the `coalesce()` part of the first insert).
- You can leave the `set constraints` statements, if your foreign key is `INITIALLY DEFERRED`.

http://rextester.com/YDY89070

Your other option is to use PL/pgSQL and a retry loop (what was the [official recommendation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) before the `ON CONFLICT` support was added).

**Edit**: it seems immediate constraints are not checked between CTE boundaries (however, I have not found any evidence for this in the docs, yet), so the `set constraints` statements & to make the foreign key deferrable is not needed.

http://rextester.com/IUSM65192

Comment: The answer below is more concise so I will accept it, but the deferred constraints checking is a really interesting feature I didn't know existed.

Comment: @IvanPoliakov the other answer in more concise, because it will leave gaps in the sequence. And also, it won't always succeed, because the `insert into ... on duplicate do update ... returning ...` won't actually return, when there was an update (instead of an insert). see: http://rextester.com/XOJ87761 -- adding those will get you my answer.